# How do I find a file containing using wildcard on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, find

I would like to know if it is possible to use find with wildcards:

I use this command, but I have an error

```
find -type f -name /target/*.zip
```

Comment: It is not clear from your posting, **what** files you are searching. The solution suggested by @Barmar assumes, that you are looking for *any* zip file somewhere below `/target`, i.e. `/target/foo/bar.zip`, but not `/foo/target/bar.zip`. Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the wildcard in quotes, otherwise it gets expanded by the shell before the command is run.

And it should just be a filename, not a pathname. The directory to start searching should be an argument to `find` before the filter specifications.

```
find /target -type f -name '*.zip'
```

Comment: Since the OP explicitly mentiones _bash_, perhaps something like a `shopt -s globstar; echo /target/**/*.zip` would also be an alternative. It depends on how the names should be processed further.